# Using sed with find to insert file content

Tags: linux

How can I add something  ex:

```
idea before </svg> in all svg files  ?

find -name "*.svg" -exec sed -i s/"</svg>"/"idea</svg>"/g {} \;
```

It doesn't work also with

```
find -name "*.svg" -exec sed -i s|"</svg>"|"idea</svg>"/g {} \;
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly it is you're trying to achieve? You want to prefix all `*.svg` files with a string, e.g. 'idea'?

Comment: how about this `find -name "*.svg" -exec sed -i 's|</svg>|idea</svg>|g' {} \;` ?

Comment: I would like to inset a string before the end tag in all svg files

Answer (score 1):

Your embedded slashes are causing sed confusion:

```
sed -i s/"</svg>"/"idea</svg>"/g    ##wrong##
```

Pick a delimiter that will NOT causing problems. Put the whole thing in quotes.

```
sed -i "s=</svg>=idea</svg>=g"
```

Comment: and good for the O.P. to notice that `sed -i s|"</svg>"|"idea</svg>"/g` should be  `sed -i 's|</svg>"|idea</svg>/g'` . Leaving it as `s|"</svg>...` "exposes" the pipe chars to shell for interpretation and action. Good luck to all.

Comment: Ack... can't believe I missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is a line editor and `sed -i.old` takes an input file to modify in place and save a copy to a `.old` file. We have to match `</svg>` and replace it with 'idea' and put the matched part back (`\1`)

```
sed -i.old 's/\(\<\/svg\>\)/idea\1/g' *.svg
```

(Notice we don't need find for this, giving `*.svg` to `sed` should suffice.)